# Django Python During Restart Data Loss

Tags: python, django

I am having the strangest problem with Django.

I have a class within a class in a module:

```
class picture(models.Model):
     picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='ProfilePictures', blank = True)

class profilePictures(models.Model):
    userName = models.CharField(max_length=30, primary_key=True)
    profilePictureNumber = models.IntegerField()
    profile1 = picture()
    profile2 = picture()
    profile3 = picture()
    profile4 = picture()
    profile5 = picture()
    profile6 = picture()
```

Now when I restart Django (for example I made an update), I type the usual:

```
python testproject.py makemigrations
python testproject.py migrate
python testproject.py runserver
```

But when the access the properties within the database in the previous run, I get nothing. So for example, I added a picture, restarted the database and then it tells me there is no picture.

I accessed the actual database with Navicat and I found out that the automatically created entries for the "picture" still exist in the database, but it appears that Django deletes the link between the two database rows (each row is a model).

I would assume there is a command to carry over this data, but I cannot seem to find it.

Comment: First `makemigrations` command is used then `migrate`. Could you try this

Comment: I typed this wrong in stackoverflow, correction was made now. I feel like the answer should be here but I can't pinpoint it: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/django-admin/

Comment: You should be using `Foreign Key` rather than creating an instance of class inside a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be having only one class `ProfilePicture` because profile picture number doesn't make any sense.

```
class profilePictures(models.Model):
    userName = models.CharField(max_length=30, primary_key=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='ProfilePictures', blank = True)
```

Or you can use `Foreign Key` to establish relationship between different tables. Documentation for `Foreign Key` is here [Foreign Key](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey)

`Example`

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    birthday = models.DateField()
    anniversary = models.ForeignKey(Anniversary)
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address)

class Address(models.Model):
    line1 = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    line2 = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    postalcode = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=150)

class Anniversary(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
```

Comment: Going off from your example, what if I want a person to have several addresses?

Comment: Your `username` is a primary key right? There can be only one instance of username. Otherwise you need to remove `primary key` from the table if you decide you use the same table.

Comment: The ForeignKey should be from Address to Person, that way you can indeed have multiple addresses for each person.